# How to make a query with dynamic column in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have the sample code below. The result is such that it takes as these columns as VARCHAR type.

```
declare @col1 varchar(80)='[Column1]'
declare @col2 varchar(80)='[Column2]'
SELECT @col1,@col2 FROM MyTable
```

Comment: you will required Dynamic SQL

Comment: Thankyou But I want to know the solution. i am seing this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure

Comment: yes. you can use that as reference

Comment: Obviously i have no idea where your final destination is with this, but i will say that this will most likely end up in an un-maintainable, ill performing mess.  There are most likely better solutions to what you really want to achieve.

Comment: Is there any better option for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @col1 VARCHAR(80) = 'Column1';
DECLARE @col2 VARCHAR(80) = 'Column2';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@col1) + ', ' + QUOTENAME(@col2) + ' FROM MyTable;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Note that you have to make sure that your column names are real column names. You also need to parameterize your query for added security. If you get any of these wrong, it may create huge security problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
declare @query nvarchar(500) = 'select ' + @col1 + ', ' + @col1 + ' FROM MyTable'
exec @query
```

Comment: should be `exec (@query)`

Comment: oh Yes Shnugo, it is resolved thats why I am thankful to you :)
But according to the Performance, is there any other alternative Option for the same ?